# Getting Stripe Charge Result From Server Android

Tags: java, android, ruby, server, stripe-payments

I'm very new to scripting and I'm having a problem finishing up my application.

I'm using Stripe for card payments in my Android application.
I send the customers information using:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("stripeToken", token.getId());
params.put("amount", amountToBeCharged);
//  params.put("body", "the message");

client.post(urlString, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

});
```

This code processes the token, however,
It doesn't let me know if the charge was failed or declined. 
How do I check In app if the charge went through?

Everything works when the cards information is entered correctly or incorrectly.

**I guess what I'm asking is:**

How do i get the result of the charge from my server to my app?

My server uses ruby.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using checkout You will get an auth token or stripe token from the stripe.Send it to the controller and create a customer and charge him using the charge call. You can verify the transaction using the reference code provided after creating a charge.

You can check this link for reference. All the docs are here. 
[This is for checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/rails).

Here is a sample code for express checkout.

```
def new
end

def create
  # Amount in cents
  @amount = 500

  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => params[:stripeEmail],
    :source  => params[:stripeToken]
  )

  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :customer    => customer.id,
    :amount      => @amount,
    :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
    :currency    => 'usd'
  )

rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  redirect_to new_charge_path
end
```